# .NET Datagrid Control Binding method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datagrid

I have 2 objects.
1) Type User which properties are Name, Surname, Email and Role

Now Role is a property type Role which its properties are RoleID and RoleName.

I wish to bind the User object with the datagrid, how can I display the Role Name in the grid since [Role] is not a string type?

Comment: Check this: http://tinyurl.com/4r2ggp2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an example code for you. I hope it will be in any help. 
I used a Linq to set the binding source:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView dgv;
    BindingList<User> bList;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgv = new DataGridView();
        dgv.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        dgv.Size = new Size(600, 200);
        this.Controls.Add(dgv);
        PopulatingDGV();
    }

    private void PopulatingDGV()
    {
        bList = new BindingList<User>();
        bList.Add(new User
        {
            Name = "John",
            SureName = "Walker",
            Email = "john@gmail.com",
            _Role = new Role { RoleID = 1, RoleName = "Role No.1" }
        });
        bList.Add(new User
        {
            Name = "Sara",
            SureName = "Johnson",
            Email = "sj@yahoo.com",
            _Role = new Role { RoleID = 2, RoleName = "Role No.2" }
        });

        //this:
        //dgv.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = bList.Select(s => new { s.Name, s.SureName, s.Email, s._Role.RoleID, s._Role.RoleName }) };
        //that:
        dgv.DataSource = bList.Select(s => new { s.Name, s.SureName, s.Email, s._Role.RoleID, s._Role.RoleName }).ToList();

        dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "User`name";
        dgv.Columns[1].HeaderText = "User`s last name";
        dgv.Columns[2].HeaderText = "E - mail";
        dgv.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Role id";
        dgv.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Role name";
    }
}

class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SureName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Role _Role { get; set; }
}

class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Mitja